# Separating a list into individual button commands on GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I currently am trying to create individual buttons from a list output in another python script. The issue I currently have is that I want to generate individual buttons for each value in the list, but instead all the values are put into 1 button.

Any help would be appreciated.

test.py:

```
def function1():
    print('Hi')

def function2():
    Greetings = ['hi there', 'ho there', 'hey there']
    print(*Greetings, sep='\n')

def function3():
    print('Hello World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function1()
    function2()
    function3()
```

GUI Application:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk

class getHellofromtest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        #clear before values are populated
        self.result = ''

    def write(self, text):
        #have to use += because one 'print()' executes 'sys.stdout' many times
        self.result += text

def getHellos():
    import test
    """
    Displays greetings obtained from test.py onto GUI application
    """
    # keep original `sys.stdout
    old_stdout = sys.stdout

    # redirect to class which has `self.result`
    sys.stdout = getHellofromtest()

    # it will execute only `function2`
    test.function2()

    # assign result to label (after removing ending "\n")
    btn1['text'] = sys.stdout.result.strip()

    # set back original `sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = old_stdout

master = tk.Tk()
btn1 = tk.Button(master, text='List of Hellos')
btn1.pack()
btn = tk.Button(master, text="Get Targets", command=getHellos)
btn.pack()
```

Comment: You code just updates the text of `btn1` with the result.  If you want to create new button for each line of result, split the result string into lines.  Then loop through the lines to create new buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the code from [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668)'s comment as an answer.
Also, if you want to display text use Labels instead of useless Buttons.

```
result = sys.stdout.result.strip()
for line in result.split(\n):
    lab = tk.Label(master, text=line)
    lab.pack()
```

Replace your line `btn1['text'] = sys.stdout.result.strip()` with this.
Hope it works:)